# Tornado failing on OSX but working on Ubuntu

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, tornado

We are doing some performance tests on Tornado. This is the code

```
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class TestTornado(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        self.set_nodelay(True)
        pass

    def on_message(self, message):
        self.write_message(message)
        self.close()

    def on_close(self):
        pass

def main():
    applicationList = []
    applicationList.append((r"/ws", TestTornado))

    application = tornado.web.Application(applicationList)
    application.listen(8888)

    myIOLoopInstance = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    myIOLoopInstance.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and we are testing with `thor --amount 10000 --messages 100 ws://localhost:8888/ws`

However, in OS X, it's always failing after 7000 connections more or less, but on Ubuntu there is no error at all. Notice I'm talking about **connections**, not about files, so the problem is not related to the max open files OS X can handle (it's already set to 1000000).

So.. why does this happen? Is there any configuration we could change on OS X to make it work?

Comment: This might belong on http://serverfault.com instead

Comment: You say "failing" - does Tornado throw an exception? Can you tell us specifically what the symptoms are?

Comment: @A.JesseJiryuDavis simply it stops to handle connections when it reaches around 7000 connections. After a while, the stress test finishes and show that all of them were "failed"

Comment: The OSX networking stack starts to perform very poorly in my experience after thousands of connections have been opened and closed. I've never figured out how to do useful network benchmarking on that platform.

Comment: @BenDarnell yep, it turns out to be OSX problems. Found this https://rolande.wordpress.com/2010/12/30/performance-tuning-the-network-stack-on-mac-osx-10-6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem in OSX itself. These parameters should help, but we are no longer testing on OS X so don't know for sure.

```
kern.ipc.maxsockbuf=4194304
kern.ipc.somaxconn=2048
kern.ipc.nmbclusters=2048
net.inet.tcp.rfc1323=1
net.inet.tcp.win_scale_factor=4
net.inet.tcp.sockthreshold=16
net.inet.tcp.sendspace=1042560
net.inet.tcp.recvspace=1042560
net.inet.tcp.mssdflt=1448
net.inet.tcp.v6mssdflt=1428
net.inet.tcp.msl=15000
net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive=0
net.inet.tcp.delayed_ack=3
net.inet.tcp.slowstart_flightsize=20
net.inet.tcp.local_slowstart_flightsize=20
net.inet.tcp.blackhole=2
net.inet.udp.blackhole=1
net.inet.icmp.icmplim=50
```

Source: https://rolande.wordpress.com/2010/12/30/performance-tuning-the-network-stack-on-mac-osx-10-6/